# Unrecognized selector sent to instance in AppDelegate

Tags: swift, timer

I am trying to get a method to be called every 5 seconds regardless if the app was open or was running in the background and so in my AppDelegate I thought it'd be a good idea to have a timer which calls a method every 5 seconds:

```
var helloWorldTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(sayHello), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)

@objc func sayHello()
{
    print("hello World")
}
```

However, I get this error:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[_SwiftValue sayHello]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

And I'm not entirely sure why because the method is referenced correctly? Does anyone understand why I'm getting this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are crashing because you can't use `self` before the AppDelegate is fully initialized (`target: self`). So you should initialize the timer in this way:

```
var helloWorldTimer:Timer?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  self.helloWorldTimer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 5.0, target: self, selector: #selector(sayHello), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
  return true
}
```

---

Quoting the Apple documentation from [Setting a Default Property Value with a Closure or Function](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Initialization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH18-ID232):

> If you use a closure to initialize a property, remember that the rest
>   of the instance has not yet been initialized at the point that the
>   closure is executed. This means that you cannot access any other
>   property values from within your closure, even if those properties
>   have default values.

moreover:

> You also cannot use the implicit self property,
>   or call any of the instance’s methods.